# Excel transpose via paste 

Tags: microsoft-excel, unicode, paste

I want to transpose data in Excel.  Normally, I cut the cells I need, and use `paste special` -> `transpose`.  However, sometimes when I do paste special, a box comes up asking me if I want to use unicode text vs normal text.

How do I transpose this text?  Is there a way to get past the unicode dialog box and get to the normal `Paste special` dialog box (that has the 'transpose' option)?

Or, is there another simple way to transpose cells?

transpose = flip rows and columns  IE 1, 2, 3 becomes:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use Excel's `Transpose` function. For example:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)
```

Do not forget to drag select cells (for example C1 to E1) which will be the location where the results will be displayed. Then type the above function and press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys on the keyboard at the same time to enter the function as an array function. Then the formula will be viewed as

```
{=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)}
```

in the formula bar above the worksheet.

Comment: Ah, excellent!  I didn't know about that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the contents onto a spreadsheet from a source that you want to transpose.  Later, copy the pasted content from your spreadsheet. While the contents are in the memory, just right click on another cell or a worksheet, and, this time, the `Paste Special` option will open with all of the features enabled.